# How to detect rightMouseDown and **otherMouseDown** on NSTableView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I want to detect rightMouseDown and **otherMouseDown** on NSTableView.
I search about it and found some answer use menuForEvent but, it invoked when right mouse **pressed** but I want to detect mouse click on nstableview.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways:

If you subclass `NSTableView`, you can override `NSResponder` `rightMouseDown:` or `otherMouseDown:` functions.

If you do not want to subclass `NSTableView`, you could attach a local monitor. The catch is that this local monitor will look at every event of the specified in the application, so you will have to do some checking to make sure the mouse was inside the table view when the right or other mouse down event happened.

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskRightMouseDown|NSEventMaskOtherMouseDown handler:^NSEvent * _Nullable(NSEvent * _Nonnull theEvent) {
    if ([theEvent window] == [tableView window]) {
        NSPoint event_location = [theEvent locationInWindow];
        NSPoint local_point = [[tableView superview] convertPoint:event_location fromView:nil];

        if (NSPointInRect(local_point, [tableView frame])) {

        }
    }

    return theEvent;
}];
```

Note that this method returns an `id` object that you will need to pass into `removeMonitor` when necessary (just like `NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName:`).